# dynamic attributes in array form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do something like this.

```
  <form onSubmit={submitForm} className=''>        
  <div> 
  // this array is a dynamic set of fields inside the form           
     {items.map((input, i)=> (
       <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
    <label htmlFor="inputResponse" className="form-label text-center" >
      <h5> Texto </h5>
    </label>              
  </div>
  <div className="row align-items-center row" key={i}>             
    <div className='col-10'>
      <input
        placeholder="desdeComponent"
        id={i}
        className='form-control mt-3'                    
        name={button value} // i would like the value of the button here.
        onChange= {handleChange((e) => e.target.name)}               
        type="text"
        required
      />
    </div>             
    ))
    }
  </div>
  
  <button className="btn btn-success me-4 mt-5"  type='submit'>AddSubmit</button>
</form>
```

I would have 3 buttons 'Add Text' 'Add Title' 'Add Link'
The thing is that I would like to add fields dynamically in my form, every time that the user clicks on the buttons.

I want to reuse the 'input' and pass the **button value** like param to the **name={button value}**, and then submit the form with all the fields at the end.

The problem is when I click 'Add Text' the name value is text name='text'.
When clicking 'Add Title', I create a new field in the form, but the name of the new field, and the old field, change to the name value to the last button that I clicked.

Is there some way to have this attribute for every field in the same array of fields?

```
const itemDataObject = {
    title_item_lateral: '' ,
    text_item_lateral: [],
    image_lateral: [
      {
        title_image_lateral: '',
        path_image_lateral: '',
      }
    ],
    document_lateral: [],
    links: [
      {
        title_link:'' ,
        link: ''
      }
    ]
  };
```

function to add fields:

```
let buttonPressed;
const addFields = (e) => {
    buttonPressed = e.target.value;
    setNameValue(buttonPressed);
    let newItemField = {itemDataObject};
      setItems([...items, newItemField]);          
    }
```

Some idea is how can i reuse and send the value to the name in every field.
Thanks

p.s:
Here is the full code: (buttons and class name are from Bootstrap 5)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const DemoLateral = () => {  
  
  const itemDataObject = {
    title_item_lateral: '' ,
    text_item_lateral: [],
    image_lateral: [
      {
        title_image_lateral: '',
        path_image_lateral: '',
      }
    ],
    document_lateral: [],
    links: [
      {
        title_link:'' ,
        link: ''
      }
    ]
  }; 
  
  let buttonPressed;
  const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(['inicial']);
  const addFields = (e) => {
    buttonPressed = e.target.value;
    setNameValue(buttonPressed);
    console.log(buttonPressed);      
    let newItemField;    
    newItemField = {itemDataObject};
    setItems([...items, newItemField]);    
  };
  
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]); 
  console.log(items);
  
  const handleChange = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
  };
  
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
  };
  
  return (
    <>      
      <h3 className="ms-5 mb-5"> AÑADIR ITEMS   </h3>
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={submitForm} className=''>        
          <div> 
            {items.map((input, i, e)=> (
              <h2 key={i} name={e.target.value}> Hola {i}</h2>
            ))
            }
          </div>
          
          <button className="btn btn-success me-4 mt-5"  type='submit'>AddSubmit</button>
        </form>
        <div className="mt-5 text-center">          
          {/*  <button className="btn btn-primary me-4"  onClick={addTextItem}>Add Text</button> */}
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='text' onClick={addFields}>Add Text</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='title' onClick={addFields}>Add Subtitle</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='image' onClick={addFields}>Add Image</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='document' onClick={addFields}>Add document</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='links' onClick={addFields}>Add Links</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value='items' onClick={addFields}>Add Items</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Paste all the related code, i tried to run, and it's missing a lot of methods

Comment: yes, this is the important part of the code that is used for this operation. if you want all, i can add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that i found was that your were using as below, the third argument 'e' is the entire array, not the event, so e.target is undefined. I added the type inside the object here `newItemField = { ...itemDataObject, button_pressed: buttonPressed };`

```
<div> 
   {items.map((input, i, e)=> ( 
      <h2 key={i} name={e.target.value}> Hola {i}</h2>
      ))
   }
</div>
```

Maybe this can give you a start:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const DemoLateral = () => {
    const itemDataObject = {
        title_item_lateral: '',
        text_item_lateral: [],
        image_lateral: [
            {
                title_image_lateral: '',
                path_image_lateral: '',
            },
        ],
        document_lateral: [],
        links: [
            {
                title_link: '',
                link: '',
            },
        ],
    };

    let buttonPressed;

    const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(['inicial']);

    const addFields = (e) => {
        buttonPressed = e.target.value;
        setNameValue(buttonPressed);
        console.log('setNameValue: ', buttonPressed);
        let newItemField;
        newItemField = { ...itemDataObject, button_pressed: buttonPressed };
        setItems([...items, newItemField]);
        console.log('Items: ', items);
    };

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = (name) => {
        console.log(name);
    };

    const submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="ms-5 mb-5"> AÑADIR ITEMS </h3>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="mt-5 text-center">
                    {/*  <button className="btn btn-primary me-4"  onClick={addTextItem}>Add Text</button> */}
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="text" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Text
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="title" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Subtitle
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="image" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Image
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="document" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add document
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="links" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Links
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary me-4 mb-4" value="items" onClick={addFields}>
                        Add Items
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success me-4 mt-5" value="submit" onClick={addFields}>
                        AddSubmit
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={submitForm} className="">
                    <div>
                        {items.map((input, i) => (
                            <h3 key={i} name={input.button_pressed}>
                                {input.button_pressed} {i}
                            </h3>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default DemoLateral;
```